# Element is in container or in a container within the container. (Python)

Tags: python, simplification

Is there a better way to code this?

```
def __contains__(self, e):
    return e in self.segments or True in [e in x for x in self.segments]
```

This function should return true if e is in self.segments or if e is in any of the segments in self.segments.

I'm still trying to learn how to use the [a for a in b if c] notations and I'm hoping that someone one StackOverflow can help me simplify that snippet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def __contains__(self, e):
    return e in self.segments or any(e in x for x in self.segments)
```

`any` stops on the first element that evaluates to `True` and, without the square brackets, Python does not create an intermediary list.

Read about [Generator Expressions vs. List Comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension)

Comment: Sorry about that... Thank you again.